# Identify a bottleneck that isn't explicit using cProfile

Tags: python

Can you help identify the bottleneck of this code? I am solving problem #7 of project Euler, and am failing to understand why this solution takes so long (30s). I know there are better solutions, I just want to understand more about why this, specifically is so bad.

```
def primes(n):
    primes = set([2])
    count = 1
    i = 1
    while count < n:
        i += 2
        if not any([i % num == 0 for num in primes]):
            primes.add(i)
            count += 1
    print i

cProfile.run("primes(10001)") #slow! 30s
```

The profile is here below:

```
62374 function calls in 34.605 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000   34.605   34.605 <string>:1(<module>)
        1   34.273   34.273   34.605   34.605 problem_7.py:8(primes)
    52371    0.328    0.000    0.328    0.000 {any}
    10000    0.004    0.000    0.004    0.000 {method 'add' of 'set' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

Comment: you might be able to speed things up by dropping the `[]` around your comprehension. That should work equivalently as a genexp but not haev to allocate a list.

Comment: Also, apart from removing [] from list comprehension, if you use list instead of set, you will gain a little performance boost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented a couple tweaks to help out. See my comments and results below. In all cases I changed the accumulator from being named `primes` (shadowing its function name) to being named `ps`. I didn't test to see if this improved performance, I just hate shadowing names :o)

---

```
# Your original code
def prime_orig(n):
    ps = set([2])
    count = 1
    i = 1
    while count < n:
        i += 2
        if not any([i % num == 0 for num in ps]):
            ps.add(i)
            count += 1

# replace the set accum with a list, per @Sheshnath's comment
def prime_list(n):
    ps = [2]
    count = 1
    i = 1
    while count < n:
        i += 2
        if not any([i % num == 0 for num in ps]):
            ps.append(i)
            count += 1

# replace the listcomp with a genexp
def prime_genexp(n):
    ps = set([2])
    count = 1
    i = 1
    while count < n:
        i += 2
        if not any(i % num == 0 for num in ps):
            ps.add(i)
            count += 1

# both optimizations at once
def prime_genexp_list(n):
    ps = [2]
    count = 1
    i = 1
    while count < n:
        i += 2
        if not any(i % num == 0 for num in ps):
            ps.append(i)
            count += 1
```

RESULTS:

```
cProfile.run('prime_orig(10001)')

         114746 function calls in 27.283 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.701    0.701   27.283   27.283 <ipython-input-2-3059f1e23ab4>:1(prime_orig)
    52371   26.330    0.001   26.330    0.001 <ipython-input-2-3059f1e23ab4>:7(<listcomp>)
        1    0.000    0.000   27.283   27.283 <string>:1(<module>)
    52371    0.250    0.000    0.250    0.000 {built-in method builtins.any}
        1    0.000    0.000   27.283   27.283 {built-in method builtins.exec}
    10000    0.003    0.000    0.003    0.000 {method 'add' of 'set' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

```
cProfile.run('prime_list(10001)')

         114746 function calls in 24.523 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.666    0.666   24.523   24.523 <ipython-input-2-3059f1e23ab4>:11(prime_list)
    52371   23.625    0.000   23.625    0.000 <ipython-input-2-3059f1e23ab4>:17(<listcomp>)
        1    0.000    0.000   24.523   24.523 <string>:1(<module>)
    52371    0.231    0.000    0.231    0.000 {built-in method builtins.any}
        1    0.000    0.000   24.523   24.523 {built-in method builtins.exec}
    10000    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

```
cProfile.run('prime_genexp(10001)')

         50627376 function calls in 10.577 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.040    0.040   10.577   10.577 <ipython-input-2-3059f1e23ab4>:21(prime_genexp)
 50565001    7.060    0.000    7.060    0.000 <ipython-input-2-3059f1e23ab4>:27(<genexpr>)
        1    0.000    0.000   10.577   10.577 <string>:1(<module>)
    52371    3.475    0.000   10.530    0.000 {built-in method builtins.any}
        1    0.000    0.000   10.577   10.577 {built-in method builtins.exec}
    10000    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 {method 'add' of 'set' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

```
cProfile.run('prime_genexp_list(10001)')

         50400891 function calls in 9.781 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.040    0.040    9.781    9.781 <ipython-input-2-3059f1e23ab4>:31(prime_genexp_list)
 50338516    6.272    0.000    6.272    0.000 <ipython-input-2-3059f1e23ab4>:37(<genexpr>)
        1    0.000    0.000    9.781    9.781 <string>:1(<module>)
    52371    3.468    0.000    9.735    0.000 {built-in method builtins.any}
        1    0.000    0.000    9.781    9.781 {built-in method builtins.exec}
    10000    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```